# Django Validate Form As Per Database Entry ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-filter

Hello Wonderful people,

I have made a form in Django which has some serial numbers stored in Django-admin database.

I am now creating another app and similar form, However I want is that the new Form should accept the serial number which is valid and checked as per the serial number got entered in the first form which is in app 1.

I am pasting a bit of my code for you to understand it more clearly with some screenshots.

```
    <form method="POST" action="/reservation/home/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Radio Serial Number</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name= "sno" 
    placeholder="S/N123ABC123" required >
        </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit </button>

      </form>
```

[image]

views.py of new app.

```
def reserve(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        sno = request.POST.get('sno')
        date_req = request.POST.get('date_req')
        reserve = Reserve( sno=sno, date_req=date_req )
        reserve.save()

    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

models.py of new app.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Reserve(models.Model):
    sno = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_req = models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
      return self.sno
```

I want it to accept the serial number which got input by another form and validate it.
If the new serial number is not same as the database entry in previous form , It should display some error message that it is not found or not valid.

If it is valid it should accept that serial number and the entry should be done in new form.
I have provided the name and id as "sno"

I am not sure how to get any documentation or any video regarding this.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

In case you need more of information, please drop a comment or check my github repository : https://github.com/samatharkar/altiostar/tree/reserve-tool/inventory/reservation_app

Comment: use django model form  == https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: If serial number is supposedly a field in another model, which I believe it is this model of yours shouldn't have this field. It should instead have a [Foreign Key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) to the other model.

Comment: @c.grey I didn't get how exactly I can achieve this with model forms. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I tried to do it but I am confused. Can you tell me where do I need to change the code exactly to achieve this? I am new to this, I tried to find any similar videos teaching this but couldn't find it. I can help you with any other information if you want ?